# PHP get last entry

Tags: php, mysql, row

So I need to find the last entry of my MySql table, I get the first one this way:

```
if($f4==0) { /*do this*/ } else { /*or do that*/ }
```

I have a table with incremented IDs, but it is sorted out by position like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM promotions ORDER BY position";
```

I would basicly need something like:

```
if($f4==Last row in table) { /*Do this*/ } else { /*Or do that*/ }
```

Comment: If it's stored with a unique, incrementing ID, just select the row with the highest ID.

Comment: your question doesn't provide any detail. please explain it

Comment: How is that piece of code get you any row from a database? Are you using PDO? What kind of columns do you have? Do you have a auto-increment column?

Comment: Edited first post with better details, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your table unique auto_increment column named `id` , you can just accomplish your task like this =>

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should use SORT (DESC) and LIMIT 1 to get a specific row.

As in Matts comment, it is good practice to use a auto imcrement column (mostly primary key) for this (alternative: timestamp/rowversion)

The more costly version is an array of all values and get the total amount of fetched values via mysql_num_rows() and then just access the row from the array with the corresponding ID (-1 because it starts at 0 and not at 1 like the mysql_num_rows function)

Answer (score 1):

With a so vague question is difficult to see what you want to do really. Please provide some more code, don't worry, we won't steal it (;

In the meanwhile, you might want to see the [MAX()](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlmax.php), which could be useful.